# How to use only part of the value of a character for x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

If I am not allowed to add an additional column, how can I select only the year data(the first column of the shown data in picture 1) to appear on the x-axis (see the desired result in picture 2)

[Picture 1:the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04LYl.png)

[Picture 2:the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENNGk.png)

Your help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an approach using `ggplot2`. In order to obtain what you want, you can use `substring()` function to extract the first four elements defining start and end position over your `quarter` variable. You can also use `factor()` to keep all years instead of showing numeric quantities as `ggplot2` uses to do. Here I have added a small example:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(quarter=paste0(rep(c(1975:1980),each=4),'-','Q',rep(1:4,6)),
                 v2=seq(0,100,length.out = 24),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(substring(quarter,1,4)),y=v2,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('year')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Duck, thank you for generous sharing! However, could you also instruct me on generating the figure that is smooth as the one shown in picture 2? I think here you created a new column “factor(substring(quarter,1,4))”, But in picture 2, 1975 Q1 and 1975 Q2 are different in terms of “x-axis”. In this case, I wonder if the desired result can be generated by using scale_x_continuous() or scale_x_discrete() instead of modifying data?

Comment: @Adriana This is just a simulated variable `v2=seq(0,100,length.out = 24)` you can change `length.out` so that it fits with your data. If I understand correctly you can change the code to this `x=factor(quarter)` so that you will display the quarters in your x-axis!